# Auto complete Jquery with value and id

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

This is my Mysql query:

```
mysql_select_db($database_final, $final);
$query_Truck = "SELECT * FROM tbl_truck";
$Truck = mysql_query($query_Truck, $final) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Truck = mysql_fetch_assoc($Truck);
$totalRows_Truck = mysql_num_rows($Truck);
```

i am having trouble in translating the recordset for the jquery autocomplete to be able to understand and access my data.

how can i get the data inside this to be in the jquery autocomplete with the id of the truck plate number being the one stored in the database and not the truck plate number itself?

Comment: For starters, you should probably use some jQuery.

Comment: mysql extension is depricated, use mysqli or pdo