# How to implement an auto complete jquery that retrieves value (id)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I need a solution like auto complete, where an user can choose something that is already in a database or if he put something that is not is the database it will be included on it.
I intend to retrieve the id, then send it to PHP and then test if the id exists. If not, make a insert.
Example:
Lets say one table with 2 fields: id and language. I have id 1 to C++, and id 2 to Java.

How to store the id value on a autocomplete jquery? How to retrieve this value? How to test if value id exist if user fill with  COBOL?

If the user fill with Javascript, it will not have id value, so it will be a new insert.

I am using the jquery auto complete UI. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#entry-examples

For now I have this code at jsfidle

http://jsfiddle.net/igoralves1/g77v4n7d/

```
<input type="text" id="autocomplete">
<button id="btn_show" type="button" >Show Val</button>


$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});



$(document).on("click", "#btn_show", function(){
    alert($("#autocomplete").val()); 
});
```

I found another similar post like same problem but not solution was found. [Auto complete Jquery with value and id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309700/auto-complete-jquery-with-value-and-id)
Any idea on how to implement hat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

http://nicolasbize.com/magicsuggest/doc.html  data option